# Python np.fromfile() adding arbitrary random comma when reading from binary file

Tags: python, numpy, random

I encounter weird problem and could not solve it for days. I have created byte array that contains values from 1 to 250 and write it to binary file from C# using WriteAllBytes.

Later i read it from Python using np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.ubyte). However, i realize this functions was adding arbitrary comma (see the image). Interestingly it is not visible in array property. And if i call numpy.array2string, comma turns '\n'. One solution is to replace comma with none, however i have very long sequences it will take forever on 100gb of data to use replace function. I also recheck the files by reading using .net Core, i'm quite sure comma is not there.

What could i be missing?

[image: weird comma from np.fromfile]

Edit:

I was trying to read all byte values to array and cast each member to **or** entire array to string. I found out that most reliable way to do this is:

```
list(map(str, (ubyte_array))
```

Above code returns string list that its elements without any arbitrary comma or blank space.

Comment: Those commas and newlines only show up in these string representations because it has a maximum line length defined. You don't need to worry about your source data, `max_line_width` is well documented in the [numpy array2string documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) - remember that a string representation of a value isn't the actual value

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).